# Correct CMakeLists.txt file for gtk, gtkmm and opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, gtk, gtkmm

I'm trying to compile a GTK2 program that uses gtkmm and opencv. I tried it with command line g++:

```
g++ main.cpp -o bla `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtkmm-2.4 opencv`
```

Which throws the same errors as output below.

And i tried it with cmake and below CMakeLists.txt file:

```
project (gtk-test)
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.4)

find_package (PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules (GTK2 REQUIRED gtk+-2.0)

include_directories (${GTK2_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories (${GTK2_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_executable (gtk-test main.c)
add_definitions (${GTK2_CFLAGS_OTHER})
target_link_libraries (gtk-test ${GTK2_LIBRARIES})
```

cmake . && make:

```
CMake Warning (dev) at CMakeLists.txt:6 (link_directories):
This command specifies the relative path

   $GTKMM_LIBRARY_DIRS}

  as a link directory.

  Policy CMP0015 is not set: link_directories() treats paths relative to the
  source dir.  Run "cmake --help-policy CMP0015" for policy details.  Use the
  cmake_policy command to set the policy and suppress this warning.
This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.

-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /Users/alefveld/Downloads/gtkcv
[ 25%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/bla.dir/MainWindow.cpp.o
In file included from /Users/alefveld/Downloads/gtkcv/MainWindow.cpp:1:
In file included from /Users/alefveld/Downloads/gtkcv/MainWindow.hpp:12:
In file included from /usr/local/include/gtkmm-2.4/gtkmm/window.h:7:
In file included from /usr/local/include/glibmm-2.4/glibmm.h:87:
In file included from /usr/local/include/glibmm-2.4/glibmm/thread.h:49:
In file included from /usr/local/include/glibmm-2.4/glibmm/error.h:23:
In file included from /usr/local/include/glibmm-2.4/glibmm/exception.h:25:
/usr/local/include/glibmm-2.4/glibmm/ustring.h:267:13: error: expected ';' at
      end of declaration list
  ~ustring() noexcept;
            ^
            ;
/usr/local/include/glibmm-2.4/glibmm/ustring.h:881:48: warning: deleted function
      definitions are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
  FormatStream(const ustring::FormatStream&) = delete;
                                               ^
/usr/local/include/glibmm-2.4/glibmm/ustring.h:882:59: warning: deleted function
      definitions are a C++11 extension [-Wc++11-extensions]
  FormatStream& operator=(const ustring::FormatStream&) = delete;
                                                          ^
/usr/local/include/glibmm-2.4/glibmm/ustring.h:894:18: error: expected ';' at
      end of declaration list
  ~FormatStream() noexcept;
                 ^
                 ;
/usr/local/include/glibmm-2.4/glibmm/ustring.h:1273:45: warning: deleted
```

And so on. What am i missing here? Any help would be eternally appreciated. How do i compile Gtk/gtkmm and opencv in one go?

Comment: Did you try to google error message? [Here](https://github.com/robotology/yarp/issues/598) they say that you need C++11 enabled.

Comment: I googled many times :-) However i did not google on C++11 errors. That seems to be helpful, thanks i will try that out.

Answer (score 1):

GTKmm and GTK are 2 different things. GTKmm are the C++ binding for GTK, so GTKmm depends on the GTK libs.

For CMake and GTKmm, just give a look at the official wiki page on [using CMake with GTKmm](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/gtkmm/UsingCMake).